# Using a VSTS CI build for a C# Class Library and NuGet push, how do you define the name of the NuGet package?

Tags: .net, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-pipelines

I have a C# class library targeting .NET 4.7.2 for which I use VSTS to build and deploy to a private NuGet package feed whenever I push a commit. This all works fine.

I also have a legacy project targeting .NET 4.0 in which I would like to make use of the above library. I have created a new branch of my library and ported it to target .NET 4.0 (had to remove some unsupported functionality) and have created a new VSTS CI build that is triggered by pushes on this branch. Again, all working fine.

The issue is that the resulting NuGet package just shows up as a new version of the .NET 4.7.2 one! Ideally I would like to have 2 packages show up in my private feed: `MyPackage` and `MyPackage.dotnet40`

Is this even possible? Or should I be doing something completely different?

### Solved

Thanks to @DanielMann's answer below I solved this problem by adding a `.nuspec` file to my project and re-configuring (slightly) my NuGet pack task in my VSTS build definition:

1. navigate to **project** root (not solution) in command prompt
2. run `nuget spec` to create a `.nuspec` file alongside your `.csproj` file (might need to add `nuget.exe` to your PATH)
3. fill out the `.nuspec` file. I replaced all the placeholders except `$version$` which VSTS automatically replaces, but you can provide values for all the placeholders in the Nuget pack task under Advanced>Additional build properties. **The important one is the `$id$` placeholder, change this to whatever you want your package to be called**
4. add the `.nuspec` to source control and commit/push
5. update the NuGet pack task so that it points to your new `.nuspec` file rather than your `.csproj` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project that's being packaged has a `.nuspec` file, change the package name in the NuSpec file.

If it's based off of the project name, change the project name.

Basically, there's no problem here -- you forked the codebase, so you have two totally separate entities that you can do whatever you want with.

Comment: hopefully you can forgive my ignorance here, I am pretty new to VSTS and creating NuGet packages! I do not have a `.nuspec` file as that is all taken care of by the VSTS build (I think) and I haven't forked the project, just created a branch; the idea being I will want to merge new features from the .NET 4.7.2 branch across into the 4.0 branch from time to time.

Comment: @Ben I'd recommend adding a `.nuspec` file in that case. You can make changes to the file in your fork and not merge those changes, or you can override the properties in it at the time of packaging. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec

Comment: Hooray! I got it working thanks to you @DanielMann! I'll update my question with the specifics though!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a separate feed and target your new project.

Comment: Thanks! This "works" in that it has allowed me to get on with things, but it isn't as neat as I'd hoped as I now have 2 packages with the same name from different feeds which I am sure will confuse the hell out of me in the future.